# getUTCHours() Javascript returns wrong hours

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var h = d.getUTCHours();
```

This should return h = 15. The current time is 3:50 PM. However it is returning h = 22.

Any ideas why ?

The minutes, seconds, month, day and year functions work fine for me.

Comment: "The current time" in which timezone?

Comment: Pacific Standard Time

Comment: You are aware what the "[UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours)" in that function name is for, right?

Comment: d = new Date(). I think its my system because the date command returns
Thu Jul  7 23:05:57 GMT 2016

Comment: `var d = new Date(); console.log(d.getUTCHours());` returns 23 as it should. 23 minutes ago when you asked a question it returned 22 as it should.

Answer (score 5):

`getUTCHours` gets the universal time (known as [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)), which is probably not the same as your local time.

I'm in San Francisco, and my local time is 15:53. However, current UTC is 22:53.

You should use [`getHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours).

In my example above:

```
var myLocalHours = new Date().getHours(); // => 15
var currentUTCHours = new Date().getUTCHours(); // => 22
```

Comment: getHours() returns 22 as well.

Comment: I think its my system because the date command returns
Thu Jul  7 23:05:57 GMT 2016

Comment: @Rsk23 yeah the first step would be to make sure you're setting your system time correctly

Comment: @Rsk23 In case you weren't aware, UTC time is the same as Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), which is London time.  In July, being on DST means GMT is 4 hours ahead of NYC, 5 hours ahead of Chicago, 6 hours ahead of Denver, 7 hours ahead of LA.  Being in the Pacific time zone, at 3:53 p.m., if you add 7 hours that is 10:53 p.m.  And your system might've been set to UTC time, instead of Pacific Daylight Time.

Answer (score 0):

Also please **make sure you're giving the timestamp in milliseconds** (if it's not multiply it by 1000), because JavaScript's expected timestamps are in millis.

I wanted this mistake to be clearly mentioned here so I added it as an answer and not as a comment for people who get wrong results and start scratching their heads :)